# Listen to mouse over events on specific words in a HTML block

Tags: gwt

I have some text which I display in the web page using GWT HTML object. This text contains a set of specific words. I want to popup something when user clicks ( also if he keeps mouse over it for sometime, if it is easy to implement that) on any of these special words.

How this could be achieved?

Please note that I have complete control over the text and I can add any specific tags around those special words if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From any event, you can easily get the exact element target using `event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget()`, which you could then check for some specific characteristics of marker elements you'd have inserted into the HTML. So, you'd attach mouse events to the `HTML` widget and use what's called "event delegation".

```java
final HTML widget = new HTML("some text with <span data-my-marker='foo'>marked words</span> in it");
widget.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      Element target = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
      // walk up until we reach a marker 'span' or the HTML widget's root element
      // just in case the marked words have markup in them
      while (!target.equals(widget.getElement())) {
        if (isMarker(target)) {
          // found a marker 'span'; process it and exit the loop
          String data = span.getAttribute('data-my-marker');
          Window.alert(data);
          break;
        }
        // otherwise, continue looping
        target = target.getParentElement();
      }
   }

   private boolean isMarker(Element elt) {
      return elt.hasTagName("span") && elt.hasAttribute("data-my-marker")
   }
});
```

(as a side note, about the use of a `data-*` attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes )

Comment: Ok, you beat me to it. Now I can delete my not yet posted answer;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new class that extends Label and implements mouseListener.

In the onHover method you create a new PopupPanel.

A good example can be found here:

http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Listeners~MouseListener

Just filter these words from your HTML object and turn them into your new Label class and put them back in the panel.

Comment: -1 for using a Listener as they are deprecated a long time ago. Also when you would put a label into the code it will insert a div or in other words will create a new line.